# With GNU GZIP environment variable deprecated, how to control ZLIB compression via tar?

Tags: compression, gzip, tar

Currently I have a script that sets compression using the `GZIP` environment variable.

With gzip 1.8 I get a warning:

```
warning: GZIP environment variable is deprecated; use an alias or script
```

How should tar be invoked so the compression level be set?

Current command:

`GZIP=-9 tar -zcf` *... files to compress ...*

Comment: This might help: https://superuser.com/a/1091640/340330

Comment: Also see https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/html_node/Environment.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can specify the compression program using: `-I` / `--use-compress-program=COMMAND`.

So the original command:

`GZIP=-9 tar -zcf` *... files to compress ...*

Becomes:

`tar -I 'gzip -9' -cf` *... files to compress ...*

*[From this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/305128/1091640#1091640).*

Comment: Getting `tar: Couldn't open gzip -9: No such file or directory` on mac -> "bsdtar 3.5.1 - libarchive 3.5.1 zlib/1.2.11 liblzma/5.0.5 bz2lib/1.0.8" - anyone else?

Comment: @NickGrealy `-I` has a different [meaning for *bsdtar*](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bsdtar&sektion=1&format=html), but it looks like `--use-compress-program` should work. Did you try that?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the OS, and the version of `tar` that ships with it. If it's BSD and/or macOS, you can just:

```
tar --options gzip:compression-level=9 -czf foo.tar.gz foo.txt
```

Otherwise, you could just take the compression stage into your own hands:

```
tar -cf - foo.txt | gzip -9 > foo.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

Some older versions of tar don't support the `-I` option to specify a compression command. So older versions cannot be used with something like `-I 'gzip -9'`.

A more portable and reliable solution is to handle the compression yourself with a pipe as mentioned in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

[*pigz*](https://github.com/madler/pigz) supports the environment variable. It is compatible with gzip, so you could install it with the name *gzip*.